# How to keep users from clicking multiple buttons at the same time?

Tags: android, buttonclick

In my app, I have a home screen with 4 buttons on it. If, for some obscure and unfathomable reason, a user were to click on more than one button at the same time, all of the target activities would open in the order they were clicked.

I have seen a couple of questions on here about something similar, but they don't really answer the question. Hopefully, I don't have to override multitouch methods to handle it.

How can I avoid this behaviour, thus preventing multiple click events at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact issue in an application I developed.  I found in testing that it was relatively easy to mash the screen with my hand and fire off onClick events for multiple buttons at the same time.

I used the same OnClickListener for all the buttons on the activity. The code was something like this :

```
protected final android.view.View.OnClickListener m_clickListener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(!m_buttonsEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.layout.button1:
                    m_buttonsEnabled = false;
                    final Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, Button1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.button2:
                    m_buttonsEnabled = false;
                    final Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, Button2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: and where to you set the boolean back to true? you turn it to false, but I don't see where you turn it back.

Comment: I set the flag true in the Activity constructor and in OnResume().  Therefore, whenever you come back to the screen the buttons will be re-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in the original activity and only open a new activity if that flag is set to false--set it to true as soon as you enter an onClick event for one of the buttons.

That being said, do you really foresee this being enough of an issue to warrant such hackiness?

Comment: personally, no i don't think it's that big of an issue. but the powers that be will probably insist i do something once the testing department says something. i'm trying to find a simple way to do this so that if they insist i can do it quickly without a huge refactor.